# Should I delete accounts I'm no longer active on?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, users, best-practices

I used to take part in the Earth Science SE actively, but now my focus has turned to StackOverflow and Arqade.

I could delete my account to show my inactivity.  But I have over 200 reputation on that account, I feel a little guilty just quitting on the site *and it looks good on my flair*.

What should I do?

Comment: Why would you delete your account? What's the problem with keeping it around?

Comment: No, it isn't obvious at all that the account should be deleted. What makes you say it should?

Comment: Well, I'm not active there and it's sorta lying to people who look at my list of communities.  I don't have a concrete reason, but it's just a burden for me.

Comment: Oh, about the lying part: don't look at my list then...

Comment: So hide it from your list.

Comment: If people keep downvoting this question, Meta will soon disappear from my flair -.-

Comment: @ShadowWizard  Hiding it does help, but on Area 51, it still says that I'm active on Earth Science.

Comment: @DominatorX true, the global flair is not affected, the only way is to delete the account.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do nothing. Leave that account as it is, and visit when you please, participate when you feel like it.

Having an account on an SE site doesn't mean you have some sort of duty in participating actively in it.

If you want to inform people that you're not active anymore on a given site, you could edit your "about me" profile section to explain that, but it isn't really necessary. People can see from your profile itself (latest questions, answers, comments, edits, ...) whether you're active or not. Feel free to leave a note though if it is important to you.

Now if you are a ♦ moderator, then things are a bit more complicated, and you should get in touch with the community moderators and your fellow site mods to see what (if anything) needs to be done.

And if you were a Stack Exchange employee, then you would need to talk to your boss or to HR, not Meta.SE :-)

Comment: This. The only people with an *obligation* to participate are moderators, and those who committed to the Area51 proposal.

Comment: @Ixrec I'd argue against the Area51 proposal committers.  I agree that they have some obligation to try to participate when the site is new, but if the site materializes in such a way that they don't like the direction it is going, why should they feel obliged to continue participating.

Comment: Who knows? Maybe a reversal's coming this way. ;)