# How to delete all my Stack Exchange accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I've decided I don't want to be a part of any Stack Exchange communities, as it's drawing my focus away from more important things (work, family, friends, etc.), so I'd like to delete all of my accounts. I've sent requests for each account individually, but is there a way to ensure that every account of mine is removed? Not the questions and answers, just the accounts? If I ever decide to come back and use the same email to log in, I want to start fresh, and I don't want it to be associated with any accounts.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. I'm not asking how to delete individual accounts, I want to delete _everything_ relating me to SE (while leaving questions and answers anonymous, of course).

Comment: There is no delete everything option, you have to follow the provided guidance for each of your 5 accounts. In that sense the duplicate holds.

Comment: @rene When I go to log in, I get the option to log in with a variety of accounts, including a StackExchange account. Is there a way to delete that login?

Comment: @user1337 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242496/i-cant-find-the-openid-delete-button - same for deleting all accounts, you'll have to email the team if you want a special treatment.

Comment: Not to offend anyone but, I posted a question on whether I should delete an account.  You posted a question on "I'm going to delete my account, how am I going to do this?"  You got 2 upvotes, I got 15 downvotes (and people criticizing me on deleting my account).  Just putting that out there.

Comment: @DominatorX I've seen a number of questions like that getting downvoted. It usually seemed to be the tone (complaining for getting called out by a moderator, wanting to delete all Q's and A's along with the account out of spite, etc), so I did my best to avoid that. This is just my decision to help me focus on more important areas of my life, no hard feelings, unlike what I've seen in those questions. I couldn't find yours, but I did upvote two of your questions, since I'll be losing my rep once the delete goes through anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for your help, I sent them a message. Hopefully they'll get back to me soon. :) I suppose if I wanted _really special_ treatment, I could just break a bunch of site rules. >.<

Comment: I did some more searching and found [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165351/i-have-24-accounts-how-can-i-delete-them-all-in-one-go). If someone could flag this as a duplicate of that, it'd probably be useful.

Comment: @user1337 I understand it's the tone that really ticks mods off, but I stuck to more of the "unsure" tone.  You can see for yourself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253876/inactive-earth-science-se-account-with-200-rep

Comment: @DominatorX It seems like the downvoting was more people disagreeing with your reasoning. They seem to think that if you're going to stay active in other communities, you might as well let it hang around. -8 is still pretty dramatic, though.

Comment: @DominatorX Your question "what should I do?", or "I don't really use this account, should I delete it" (that's how I read it, if I'm wrong you should edit and clarify your real question), was voted on.  The votes came up negative, or "no, you shouldn't do that".  If that's confusing, it may be solely because you were not clear in your question.  Seems straightforward and clear to me, however.